# Is it possible that i have Azure Sql DB Connection String, And I can use database from online portal [ without any other credentials ]

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Is it possible that i have Azure Sql DB Connection String,

And I can use database from online portal [ without any other credentials ]
[Not from local SSMS but any online tool ]

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with the database? You can log into the Azure Portal and do management operations on the database without needing to connect via SSMS. Are you trying to query the database?

Comment: @elfisher I saw you adding the two tags. It would seem to my layman's eye that the two tags should be synonyms, and added a corresponding question [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308533/synonymize-azure-sql-database-to-sql-azure). I can also see that you added the tag wiki for the new tag. I would love to hear your input on the matter:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak you are correct. I'll add comments to your post and leave this one for the main question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

This feature appears to no longer exists in the v12 databases.  You need to use the older SQL Database for the browser based administration.  Otherwise, I would suggest using the Visual Studio 2015 Server Explorer or SQL Server Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any as long it has the necessary drivers to connect to it. Most tools (online or not) that work with newer SQL Server will probably connect to Azure SQL Server. In the past, Microsoft had a web-based tool to manage the database but it's now deprecated. Best options are Visual Studio or SSMS if Windows. For Mac OSX or Linux, there is RazorSQL. There's also SQLPro for MSSQL for Mac OSX.

You can get the connection string by selecting your database in the portal and clicking "Show Connection String" in quick glance.

[image]